# render angular tags from html string - angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf

I'm trying to convert my web page in angular 2 to a pdf document.
with innerHtml I get only simple tags of html it doesn't know how to
render angular tags.
I know there is a ComponentResolver that gets a component and renders it to
the wanted component.
but I need to get all the contnet of my page as html string including both html and angular tags.(get the angular tags rendered!)
is there any way????

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.